# c# How to get string from byte?

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a form-console application which does a TCP socket connections for send and receive.
I need help getting the following response to STRING.
The following code does write the RESPONSE to the console, but i also want to

```
      byte[] b = new byte[100];
        int k = s.Receive(b);
        Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));

        ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
        s.Send(asen.GetBytes("RECEIVED :"));
```

i want to get something like

```
    String GETSTRING;
    byte[] b = new byte[100];
    int k = s.Receive(b);
    Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));

     GETSTRING = *WHATEVER RESPONSE RECEIVED ABOVE*

    ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
    s.Send(asen.GetBytes("RECEIVED :"));
```

=======================================================

**Part 2** 
How can i make it in that sense that it's always "WAITING" for response from another client
and will not spam my writeline to the console?

```
                IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
                TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 8001);

                myList.Start();

                Console.WriteLine("The local End point is  :" +
                                  myList.LocalEndpoint);
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");
                Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

                byte[] b = new byte[100];
                int k = s.Receive(b);

                while(***something here***){
                Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");

               for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));

               ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
              s.Send(asen.GetBytes("RECEIVED :"));
              }
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a massive issue with your implementation... TCP sockets do not necessarily receive the entire message at once - you may receive only part of the message when calling `Receive`. You probably have not encountered this yet because you're testing locally and there's no real network latency. Therein lies the difficulty of Sockets.

You need to loop Receive until you receive everything. But you can't know that you've received everything until you create a custom protocol layer that gives your receiver the number of bytes that will follow to complete the message.

Give my open source library, SimplSockets a try. It frames the message correctly for you, circumventing the above issues. http://www.github.com/ironyx/simplsockets

To answer your original question, it depends on your desired encoding. If you want to support pretty much all possible characters, I'd use:

```
string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes[]);
```

Comment: it's just for testing purpose. i added while loop under int k = s.Receive(b);

then the console spammed show my received data when i only need one.


How can i code it so that it would be "waiting for my send" and only show one entry to the console instead of spamming?

Comment: As mentioned above, you need to receive the COMPLETE message before outputting it to the console. Which means you need to create a protocol layer that tells your receiver how many bytes are to follow in order to complete the message. My library does this all for you automatically, but nothing stops you from giving it a go yourself or using my code as an example. :)

Answer (score 0):

`String value = System.Text.Encoding.ASCIIEncoding.GetString(byte_buffer);`

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 0, b.Length);
```